# Forwarding variadic arguments containing non copyable types

Tags: d

```d
void print1(Args...)(Args args){
    print2(args);
}
void print2(Args...)(Args args){
    //do something
}
```

And you can call it like this

```d
print1(1, 2);
```

But what if there is a non copyable type inside the variadic argument?

```d
struct Foo{
    @disable this(this);
    ~this(){
    }
}
```

then

```d
print(1, 2, Foo());
```

> Error: struct app.Foo is not copyable because it is annotated with @disable

It should be possible with mixins

```d
void print1(Args...)(Args args){
    mixin(forward!(print2, Args));
}
```

which would expand to

```d
// with `print(1, 2, Foo());`
void print1(Args...)(Args args){
    mixin("print2(args[0], args[1], args[2].move()");
}
```

Are there any other alternatives besides this? Does something like this already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `print1` and `print2` functions are accepting function parameters by-value, meaning they are copied when passed in. This, of course, does not work with non-copyable values (unless you move them in, which invalidates the source value).

To accept non-copyable values, you need to pass them by-reference. The easiest way to do that with variadic templates is by using `auto ref`:

```
void print1(Args...)(auto ref Args args) { ... }
```

With `auto ref`, any arguments that can be passed by-reference will be.

You can also combine this with [`std.functional.forward`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_functional.html#.forward):

```
void print2(Args...)(auto ref Args args) { ... }
void print1(Args...)(Args args) {
    print2(forward!args);
}
```